# Conditionally include project in gradle build

Tags: android, build, gradle

Scenario: We have an Android app with a few different optional components that we would like to be able to include/exclude depending on customer needs and licensing.  Is it possible to include specific projects based on a build parameter **and without creating all permutations as build flavors**?

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -PincludeFeatureA=true -PincludeFeatureB=false
```

I thought I could do something like this in dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  if(includeFeatureA){
    compile project(':featureAEnabled')    
  } else {
    compile project(':featureADisabled')
  }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Update: Considering the number of toggle-able features, using explicit build variants for every permutation is cumbersome.

For example, given 3 toggle-able features, I do not want to have to build flavors like this:

```
Feature1
Feature1-Feature2
Feature1-Feature3
Feature1-Feature2-Feature3
Feature2
Feature2-Feature3
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution for my scenario was to move the `if` statement out of the dependencies:

Assuming the command line:

```
gradlew assembleRelease -PincludeFeatureA
```

At the beginning of the project build.gradle, I include this:

```
def featureA_Proj=':featureA_NotIncluded'
```

Then I have a task like this:

```
task customizeFeatureA(){
    if(project.hasProperty('includeFeatureA')){
        println 'Including Feature A'
        featureA_Proj=':featureA'
    }
}
```

Finally, under dependencies, I just include:

```
dependencies{
  include(featureA_Proj)
}
```

Comment: What happens if -PincludeFeatureA is not given?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Build Variants](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants). You can enable or disable dependencies on the projects based on them You can even use separate assets or source code with them.

Comment: Updated my question for what I'm trying to avoid.  I'm familiar with build variants, but when you have more than a couple of toggleable features, they get unwieldy. Perhaps, there's a way to generate the variants at build time..

Answer (score 1):

Check out the settings.gradle file, it can be used to indicate which all projects to build, here you might be able to read the settings set and use those.

See
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

That might help.